# Initialize QuartzScheduler when container first loads web application

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to follow up the steps as mentioned in the  "**Quartz Scheduling frame work**"  book "**Initializing Quartz within the Web Application**" Example.  Here is the link for the program https://gist.github.com/5777d9f27c700e716a5a.  But the example is on Struts1 framework.

Ours is a struts2 framework with Hibernate 3.5 ORM. How should i configure the exact steps on Struts2. Any help would be appreciated.

But if i write the code within contextInitialized() method i am getting the exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/hibernate.cfg.xml (No such file or directory)"

```
Xml config = new Xml("src/hibernate.cfg.xml", "hibernate-configuration");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.driver", config.child("session-
                                      factory").children("property").get(1).content());
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.URL", config.child("session-
                                      factory").children("property").get(2).content());
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.user", config.child("session-
                                      factory").children("property").get(3).content());
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.password", config.child("session-
                                      factory").children("property").get(4).content());
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.tasksDataStore.maxConnections", "20");

SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(prop);
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
```

Comment: if the solution works for you, i suggest you tick the answer so as to help other users.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for me.. Thanks..:) I am using a class that implements ServletContextListener &  Instantiates the Quartz Scheduler class and starts the scheduler. But the hibernate.cfg.xml (db connection properties is one issue thats left)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To initialize the Scheduler when the container loads, you can do this.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class QuartzServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    public static final String QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY = "org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY";
    private StdSchedulerFactory factory = null;

    /**
     * Called when the container is shutting down.
     */
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        try
        {
            factory.getDefaultScheduler().shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException ex)
        {
        }

    }

    /**
     * Called when the container is first started.
     */
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        try
        {
            factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

            // Start the scheduler now
            factory.getScheduler().start();
            ctx.setAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY, factory);

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In your web.xml, add

```
<listener>
    <description>A Listener Class to initialize Quartz Scheduler</description>
    <listener-class>full_package_path.QuartzServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This basically creates the scheduler when the container loads. You can then use my previous post to retrieve the `StdSchedulerFactory` from the `StdSchedulerFactory`.
Let me know if there are issues.

Comment: This is a good example, but you should really do something with the exceptions you catch. You may have omitted them for brevity's sake, but a lot of people who run across this will just blindly copy/paste it.

Comment: Thanks for the example, One query i am left with is the DB connection properties at the time of initializing. So, far i was getting the db connection properties from hibernate.cfg.xml and add it to SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties). You can check the code for that in my post.

Comment: Where is your src/hibernate.cfg.xml located in your application.

Comment: before build its in src/hibernate.cfg.xml. But after the build its in /WEB-INF/Classes/hibernate.cfg.xml.  I tried specifying both paths. but none of them works.

Comment: if actually the instantiation, `Xml config = new Xml("src/hibernate.cfg.xml", "hibernate-configuration");` reads from the class path, i suggest you remove src/. do this `Xml config = new Xml("hibernate.cfg.xml", "hibernate-configuration");`

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you need to configure [QuartzInitializerServlet](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) in your web.xml.
2. Secondly, your Struts2 action needs to implement [ServletContextAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/ServletContextAware.html) interface. This interface has a method that sets the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).
3. You can then proceed to receive your StdSchedulerFactory.

`public class MyClass implements ServletContextAware`
    {

```
private ServletContext context;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext context)
{
    this.context = context.
}

public String execute()
{
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory)context.getAttribute(QuartzFactoryServlet.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);

    // Retrieve the scheduler from the factory
    Scheduler scheduler = factory.getDefaultScheduler();
}

}
```

Hope this is clearer.

Comment: so, when the container loads, it will enter into the execute method? and what does the "execute()" method return as String ?

Comment: This wont run when the container loads.

Comment: No the execute method is not called when the container loads. If you want the `StdSchedulerFactory` to be instantiated when the container loads, you can implement and register a `ServletContextListener` and initialize the Scheduler in the `contextInitialized` method.